# Issue with AWS S3 Presigned URL with session token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having an issue generating a presigned url for AWS S3 if my credentials are using a session token.  I am getting the following error:

```
<Code>InvalidToken</Code>
<Message>The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.</Message>
```

I am getting the error in my code using AWS Amplify, but I can reproduce the issue using the CLI directly.  When I use a profile that doesn't have a session-token, the url returned from the cli command works.  But when I use a profile that does have a session-token, the url from the cli command doesn't work and has the above error

```
# this returned url will work
aws --profile=some-profile-without-session-token --region=us-east-2 s3 presign s3://a-valid-bucket/a-valid-key

# this returned url will not work
aws --profile=some-profile-with-session-token --region=us-east-2 s3 presign s3://a-valid-bucket/a-valid-key
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you testing the URL from the second awscli example? Did you also attempt to get an object using the regular `aws --profile=xyz --region=us-east-2 s3 cp s3://a-valid-bucket/a-valid-key .`?

Comment: I am just clicking on the returned url.  The first one opens up in the browser and shows the image that originally was uploaded.  But the second (session one) opens in the browser with that error

Comment: I tried the cp command and I am getting the following error... so maybe it is a permission issue?

fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Comment: I made the image in S3 public and now the cp command works, but still getting the token error when trying to create a presigned url

so this works, it downloads the image

`aws --profile=with-session --region=us-east-2 s3 cp s3://a-valid-bucket/a-valid-key ~`      

however, the following command still doesn't work (it does create a URL, but that URL just returns the above malformed token error)

`aws --profile=with-session --region=us-east-2 s3 presign s3://a-valid-bucket/a-valid-key`

Comment: How are you testing the pre-signed URL? Browser, curl, wget? If from the command line, be sure to enclose the entire pre-signed URL in quotes e.g. `curl "<url>" --output tempfile`

Comment: I am just clicking the url that is outputted from the cli command in the terminal which opens it in Chrome.  The url is urlencoded (the slashs and + that are in the session token are encoded)

Comment: @dan , I'm getting a similar error with a new stack that I deploy. I suspect it's about the combination of new bucket + lambda session key

Comment: i will look into that.  please let me know if you resolve the blocker on your end